# Load image from server to my app using volley.jar

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load images and a string value corresponding to each image from server to my android app in a listview using volley.jar library.I am not able to get this working and couldn't find out what i did wrong. I appreciate if anyone could please tell me what i did wrong.

I have got a Movie class where i have declared methods to get and set variables titles and thumbnailUrl

This is my CustomListAdapater class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Movie> movieItems;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This in my MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "---------------------my api url-------------";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        try {
            getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.e(TAG+" response", response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("description"));
                                String logo = obj.getString("logo");
                                String src ="------------Image directory path-------------"+logo;
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(src);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }
}
```

This is what i am getting in my logcat

```
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/TextLayoutCache﹕ Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
I/Adreno200-EGLSUB﹕ <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51edf000 size:307200 offset:0 fd:64
D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
I/Adreno200-EGLSUB﹕ <ConfigWindowMatch:2218>: Format RGBA_8888.
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5203a000 size:8990720 offset:7454720 fd:67
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5293d000 size:614400 offset:307200 fd:70
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x529d3000 size:20766720 offset:19230720 fd:73
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x53ea1000 size:921600 offset:614400 fd:76
D/Volley﹕ [1] 2.onErrorResponse: MainActivity
D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 3487 ms: [ ] http:----------------------------myApi.php 0xcb62917f NORMAL 1
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51edf000 size:307200 offset:0
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x5293d000 size:614400 offset:307200
D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x53ea1000 size:921600 offset:614400
D/CLIPBOARD﹕ Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
```

Comment: I have found out where i made the mistake. Actually the mistake was that the method was returning JSONArray values and i was trying to get JSONObject directly from it without explicitly converting it ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Picasso a powerful image downloading and caching library for Android, you simply need to include the jar file and write one line of code for further details follow link:

[Picasso library for Android](http://square.github.io/picasso/)